Powershell - Sign String with Exported Private Key and with Algorithm RSA-SHA512
I'm trying to Sign a String with Private Key (From pfx Certificate) and with Algorithm RSA-SHA512
in Powershell.
Here is what i have now:
$x_request_id = New-Guid
$x_request_id_Final = "x-request-id: $x_request_id"

$string = ""
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($string)
$sha512 = [System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512]::Create()
$hash = $sha512.ComputeHash($bytes)
$Digest = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($hash)
$Digest_Final = "digest: SHA512=$Digest"

$SignString = $Digest_Final + "`n" + $x_request_id_Final

my output looks like this:

digest: SHA512=z4PhNX7vuL3xVChQ1m2AB9Yg5AULVxXcg/SpIdNs6c5H0NE8XYXysP+DGNKHfuwvY7kxvUdBeoGlODJ6+SfaPg==
x-request-id: f1856125-24bd-47c1-a1af-1ab6bd507634


so far everything is ok.
now i have a private key which i pulled from PFX Certificate, lets called it "Certificate.pfx"
and it's content looks like this:
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
Base64ContentHere
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----

Does anyone knows had any experience signing String with private key with the Algorithm RSA-SHA512 in powershell?

Never heard of "singing a string" before. It could be me but it might make sense to do some references how this is supposed to work in other languages or so. Anyways, more common would be document - or code signing. Saying that, you might consider to put a quoted string in a PowerShell (.ps1) file and sign that and than you could securily invoke that with $String = . .\SignedString.ps1 using Set-ExecutionPolicy

@iRon well, this procedure has been done by someone from my organization, he used javascript and some functions which he doesnt know what they are doing behind them, so since he has no idea what is going on behind i cant know either. also the "empty string" is a thing because it works and i do get the correct data. if it helps the function he using is "crypto.createSign(algorithm)"

so I solved my issue with a workaround that I had to build (Solved my problem)
I first had to find an old openssql which support dgst -sha512.
Looking over the internet i found the following windows exe file:
openssl for windows
After downloading the file I placed it in a folder on my server and did the following:
$x_request_id = New-Guid
$x_request_id_Final = "x-request-id: $x_request_id"

$string = <String>
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($string)
$sha512 = [System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512]::Create()
$hash = $sha512.ComputeHash($bytes)
$Digest = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($hash)
$Digest_Final = "digest: SHA512=$Digest"

[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText('c:\temp\data.txt', "$Digest_Final`n$x_request_id_Final")
& "c:\temp\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\openssl.exe" dgst -sha512 -sign "c:\temp\privatekey.pem" -out "c:\temp\signature.bin" "c:\temp\data.txt"
& "c:\temp\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\openssl.exe" base64 -in "c:\temp\signature.bin" -out "c:\temp\signature_base64.txt"
$Final = (Get-Content "c:\temp\signature_base64.txt") -replace "`r`n",""

$CERT = Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\my\<ID>
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[string],[string]]"
$headers.Add(<Add headers>)
etc...

Invoke-WebRequest "<URL>" -Method "Post/Get" -Headers $headers -CertificateThumbprint $CERT.Thumbprint

that's how I solved my problem with a little workaround, I'm sure there is a better way to do that, but since I was short on time I didn't had much time to find the right modules.
i hope it will help someone in the feature.
